# Hover effect like egg

Tags: css, animation, hover

I'm trying to create a hove like the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eBIH.jpg. This is what I have done. But the shape is not exactly like the image. What do you think?

```css
.circle {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.circle:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 60% 60% 40% 40%;
  width: 80px;
  margin-left: 35px
}

.text {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="text">HELLO</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below snippet i got closer, still if you want to get more closer you can try this online useful [tool](https://9elements.github.io/fancy-border-radius/)

```css
.circle {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.circle:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 58% 42% 48% 52% / 49% 25% 75% 51%;
  width: 80px;
  margin-left: 35px
}

.text {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="text">HELLO</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.circle {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.circle:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 78% 22% 69% 31% / 67% 16% 84% 33%;
  width: 80px;
  margin-left: 35px
}

.text {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="text">HELLO</div>
</div>
```